# $_SESSION nao persiste em outras paginas na aplicaçao

Tags: codeigniter

boa noite pessoal,

estou utilizando o codeigniter e session nativa do php $_SESSION, acontece que so consigo utilizar a session quando instancio em um controller de login que redireciona para uma outra pagina, mas se eu quiser utilizar as informaçoes dessa session em outra pagina nao consigo, diz q a session nao existe. ja quebrei a cabeça aki ja tentei de tudo um pouco mas nao consigo prosseguir na minha aplicaçao sem antes resolver essa questao, gostaria mto da ajuda do pessoal que manja um pouco mais. obrigado a todos!

controller (essa parte funciona de boa ea view admin recebe tranquilo a session o problema eh se eu quiser utilizar as informaçoes dessa session em outras views informa q nao existe)

```
public function check_login()
{
    $login = $this->input->post('login');
    $pass =  md5(md5(md5($this->input->post('pass'))));

    $user = $this->login_model->checkLogin($login, $pass);

    if(!$user)
    {

        $data['msg_erro'] = "Login ou senha inválido.";
        $this->load->view('index', $data);


    }
    else{

        if($user->cod_user == 1)
        {


            $_SESSION['ci_session'] = $user->name;
            $this->load->view('admin');


        }
        else if($user->cod_user == 2)
        {
            $_SESSION['vendedor'] = $user->name;

            $this->load->view('vendedor');
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Mesmo que não vá usar especificamente nenhum método dela, carregue a [Session Library](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#using-the-session-class).

Answer (score 1):

Então amigo, antes de você poder cria ou pegar o valor de uma super variável $_SESSION, e preciso primeiro inicia a sessão `session_start()`, uma unica vez em cada pagina que for necessário criar ou pegar uma $_SESSION.

Particularmente eu acho mais recomendável usar a librarie session do CI.

para você cria uma sessão com a librarie session do CI, seria:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('nameSession', 'valueSession');
```

e para pegar uma session,seria:

```
$this->session->userdata('nameSession');
```

lembrando que você deve carregar a librarie antes de usar, que pode ser feito tanto no autoload como no controller.

carregando librarie no autoload do CI: `Application/config/autoload.php`

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session');
```

carregando librarie no controller:

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

se você carregar uma librarie no autoload, ela estará disponível em toda a aplicação, já se você carregar ela no controller, elá estará disponível somente no controller carregado, caso você precise usar ela em outro controller sera preciso carregar ela novamente.

seu código ficaria assim usando a librarie do CI:

```
public function check_login()
{
    $login = $this->input->post('login');
    $pass =  md5(md5(md5($this->input->post('pass'))));

    $user = $this->login_model->checkLogin($login, $pass);

    if(!$user)
    {
        $data['msg_erro'] = "Login ou senha inválido.";
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }
    else{

        if($user->cod_user == 1)
        {   
            $session['admin'] = $user->name;
            $this->session->set_userdata($session);
            $this->load->view('admin');
        }
        else if($user->cod_user == 2)
        {
            $session['vendedor'] = $user->name;
            $this->session->set_userdata($session);
            $this->load->view('vendedor');
        }
    }
}
```

você pode conferir mais detalhes na documentação do CI: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score -4):

Olá, não sei se sua session está inicializada no arquivo autoload, se não estiver, pode tentar. No meu caso estava e não funcionava. Retirei de lá efiz o seguinte:

```
   session_start();
   $_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

Já no controller onde precisava receber:

```
  session_start();
  print_r($_SESSION);
  die();
```

Espero que ajude!